# How to upload a file using jQuery.ajax and FormData

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, file-upload, xmlhttprequest

When I use XMLHttpRequest, a file is correctly uploaded using [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XMLHttpRequest/FormData). However, when I switch to [`jQuery.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), my code breaks.

This is the working original code:

```
function uploadFile(blobFile, fileName) {
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append("fileToUpload", blobFile);
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", "upload.php", true);
    xhr.send(fd);
}
```

Here is my unsuccessful `jQuery.ajax` attempt:

```
function uploadFile(blobFile, fileName) {
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append("fileToUpload", blobFile);
    var xm = $.ajax({
        url: "upload.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: fd,
    });
}
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I get the file to be uploaded correctly, using AJAX?

Answer (score 174, accepted):

You have to add `processData:false,contentType:false` to your method, so that jQuery does not alter the headers or data (which breaks your current code).

```
function uploadFile(blobFile, fileName) {
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append("fileToUpload", blobFile);

    $.ajax({
       url: "upload.php",
       type: "POST",
       data: fd,
       processData: false,
       contentType: false,
       success: function(response) {
           // .. do something
       },
       error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorMessage) {
           console.log(errorMessage); // Optional
       }
    });
}
```

Comment: I'd upvote this 1000 times if i could. Out of all the other answers to this question on SO, this one worked the best and is the simplest. thanks.

Comment: Warning: FormData is not supported in IE until version 10.

Comment: In this answer (and question), what is `blobFile`? Is it an input.val()?

Comment: @tmyie It is a [`Blob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) or [`File`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) object, e.g. for `<input type="file" id="filechooser">` it is `document.getElementById('filechooser').files[0]` (provided that the user has selected a file). (in jQuery, `$('#filechooser')[0].files[0]`)

Comment: @ScottD.Strader f$%#@ IE 9 and 8, they are only stopping the progress... :D

Comment: Please, and if I want to send another data too, like string fields, how this should word?

Comment: @MarceloBarbosa `fd.append('field_name', 'string_field_value');` - see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData

Comment: lets say you have successfully send the file through ajax how would you retrieve it in the php file if for example like this how can you get this in the upload.php?how can you insert it?

Comment: @HogRider `$_FILES['fileToUpload']`, as usual. This is not different from a normal form submission.

Comment: @RobW, do you know how to set in the "fd" the Content-Type (image/jpeg) ?
Thanks.

Comment: @Or9400 The fd's content type? I guess that you meant setting the MIME-type of the file? You can change the MIME-type of a `File` using the [`Blob` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob). For example, if you want to force the `image/jpeg` MIME-type for the file in the example, use `blobFile = new Blob([blobFile],{type:'image/jpeg'});` before `fd.append`.

Comment: @RobW, It's was like this, my problem was the order of the S3 fields.
'    fd.append('acl', 'public-read-write');
    fd.append('key', fileName);
    fd.append('Content-Type', file.type);
    fd.append("file", file); '

Thanks.

Comment: Is there any way to change MIME type of filies while  sending files to server in ajax call?

Comment: @Jaimin The Blob constructor takes a "type" parameter that specifies the MIME-type. See my content above from 11 May 2015.

Comment: I have a problem when the file is bigger than 10MB. Does any one know why?

Comment: can you check your answer cause I don't see where the parameter `fileName` is applicable inside the function. Maybe a bug or a typo?

Comment: @JoãoPimentelFerreira `fileName` came from the code snippet in the original question. If you want to preserve the file name, use `fd.append("fileToUpload", blobFile, fileName);`.

Comment: @RobW just saying that the function as it is written it's not clear, cause that parameter is redundant. I would edit it to introduce that line of code you just referred

Answer (score 0):

If you are uploading from a HTML5 form that includes an input fo type file you can just use querySelector and FormData and it works.

In case of php it will give you all files in the $_FILE and all other inputs in the $_POST array.

JS/jQuery:

```
function safeFormWithFile()
{
  var fd = new FormData(document.querySelector('#myFormName'));

  $.ajax({
        url:'/catchFormData.php',
        method:'POST',
        data:fd,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success:function(data){
          console.log(data);
        }
  });
}
```

HTML:

```
<form id="myFormName">
  <input id="myImage" name="myImage" type="file">
  <input id="myCaption" name="myCaption" type="text">
</form>
```