# HTML5 file upload: what should be append to FormData

Tags: jquery, html

This post looks promising, but I can't figure out what is `blobFile` in the code? Where can I get this variable?

[How to upload a file using jQuery.ajax and FormData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9622901/how-to-upload-a-file-using-jquery-ajax-and-formdata)

*Extra question:*

I assume that `FormData` object contains data in **ALL** input fields **including** file input. But it seems not the case. Otherwise we don't need to append the file data to `FormData`. Could anyone explain why file input is not included in the `FormData`?

Also, I use Django backend, which by convention access uploaded files in `request.FILES`. How can I put file data in `request.FILES` rather than `request.POST` with `$.ajax()`?

**EDIT**
I just figured out that NOTHING is in my `request.POST` and `formData` in empty. can't figure out why.. Here is relevant code:

// html

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
    <span class='file-name' id='file-name-1'>FILE 1</span>
    <input type="file" id='id_image'>
    <input class="browse-click" type="button" value="+"/>
    <input id="send" type="submit" value="change">
</form>
```

// js

```
<script>
    // when button is clicked, the file browser opens
    $('.browse-click').on("click" , function () {
        $('#id_image').click();
    });

    // upload file async when file is selected in file browser
    $('#id_image').on('change', function () {
        var currentpath = window.location.pathname;
        var formData = new FormData($('form')[0]);
        formData.append('csrfmiddlewaretoken', '{{ csrf_token }}');
        $.ajax({
            url: currentpath,  //server script to process data
            type: 'POST',
            xhr: function() {  // custom xhr
                var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
                if(myXhr.upload){ // check if upload property exists
                    myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress',progressHandlingFunction, false); // for handling the progress of the upload
                }
                return myXhr;
            },
            data: formData, 
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
        });
    });

    function progressHandlingFunction(e){
        if(e.lengthComputable){
            $('progress').attr({value:e.loaded,max:e.total});
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Web%2FAPI%2FXMLHttpRequest%2FFormData) data object can be instantiated with a form element or without.
If it is instantiated with a form element all the fields in the form will be automatically added to the form data object.
If it isn't (which is the case in the question you linked to) then you have to add all the fields to the form data manually with the append method.
`blobFile` is most likely a [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob), you can also use [File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FFile)s which you can get from file inputs.

Comment: Could you provide code example? I use `var formData = new FormData($('form')[0]);`, but still get NO file upload in request. POST. don't know what's going wrong

Comment: @Philip007 are there any other forms in the document? Also show the form html and the js used to ajax it.

Comment: No, that's not the only form. But it's the first form in the html. Is it not `$('form')[0]` refers to? Also I post the code in edit.

Comment: @Philip007 Try adding an id to your form and specifically selecting it. Also `$('#id_image').click();` won't work in IE.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I set file input field's id to `form1`, then `var formData = new FormData( $('#form1')  );`. Now I don't get any xhr request sent at all!

Comment: @Philip007 you forgot the [0], `$('#form1')[0]`

Comment: IT WORKS NOW! THANK YOU. Yet I am getting confused of the `form[0]` syntax. Which element exactly does it get? Could you explain it in your answer for newbies like me?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30656/discussion-between-musa-and-philip007)