# Can I use javascript to construct a virtual file of browser generated data for submission to a server

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was looking at what my own server accepts, and it is looking for JSON files, which i double checked with my colleagues and confirmed.

My question is this:

If I have a Javascript object, and need to sent it to the server as a file?  How would that be done?  I was thinking that I would need to use a hidden iframe or something and then submit it.

I was hoping there was some way to say:

```
var _JS_OBJ_ = {/* ... */}
var f = File(JSON.stringify(_JS_OBJ_));
// ...
// submit a multipart form -OR- $.ajax({.....});
```

I was hoping there was a way to create a virtual file which isnt actually saved to the client machine, which would alleviate the client-server file downloading restrictions.  That way since it isnt saved, i could create a dynamic file to upload to a server via a AJAX call.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255344/how-can-i-use-jquery-to-post-json-data

Comment: I know how JSON works, and do that all the time, but the servers accept JSON FILES, not JSON objects.... So i was thinking that i would need to create a temp file, store a string in there, and then post that file to the server.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5587973/javascript-upload-file

Comment: @Fallenreaper Incorrect.  The server accepts a long string of 1's and 0's -- that at a slightly higher level is checked to be a string representing a JSON object.  If it wants to save those on the disk drive as part of the file system, that is the server's business.

Comment: Yea, i also of input[type=file] but that is obtained through the local client machine.  Can you tie a file input to that of a dynamically created javascript File?

Comment: @Paul would there be a different header used to say this is an incoming file though?  I am unsure if that json uploaded via 'data' of a Ajax call would suffice or if there is something else i should do to encapsulate the JSON such that when the server recieves it, it says "OH This is a file." etc.  If i submitted the json via DATA in saying it is a multipart file, or something would that work, or is there something i am missing.

Comment: @Fallenreaper there is no JSON object. JSON is a serialized representation of a javscript object - you send a string, the server takes care of saving to filesystem / db / whatsoever.

Comment: Someone could set up a server to  accept file uploads, and expect those files to contain json.  That is pretty rare, it is just not done because it doesn't facilitate automation like ajax does.

Comment: @Paul that what i have to work with.  So i guess i am the 1%.

Comment: @moonwave99 my mistake, wrong vocab.  I have a javascript object that i want to save into a file and then upload that file to the server, without it saving locally (As there are sec issues when downloading files to a computer.

Comment: Try looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery  --- or maybe not.  Not sure this will let you upload your own data as a file.

Comment: Perhaps an interesting question is "Can I use javascript to construct a virtual file upload of browser generated data from the browser to a server's standard receiving handler normally paired to a HTML file input tag?"

Comment: I mean, that sounds exactly like what i want to do.... Maybe i should reform my question such that it is properly answered.

Comment: It looks like FormData is a new HTML 5 object that helps with this.

Comment: Too bad, not all users of my page would be using HTML5.  I feel forcing it would be bad news bears.  *sigh*  Maybe there is some sort of iframe hack i could use to obtain the same sort of outcome?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9622901/how-to-upload-a-file-using-jquery-ajax-and-formdata

Comment: The old way was to use flash or iframes.  Some people were looking for progress indicators instead of pushing their own data, though.

Comment: http://caniuse.com/xhr2

Comment: MMMM, what if i printed the Javascript to a hidden iframe, and then pushed the iframe to the server via a request... or something similar as the only stuff in the iframe would be the output of javascript...  and in a way, that is a file that is loaded.  sort of?

Comment: Sorry if all this wasn't helpful, might want to pin down your exact problem a bit more, since there are many interesting problems that may or may not be your problem.

Comment: I've never seen someone upload the contents of an iframe.  The HTML file tag is the primary thing I would turn to, to set the browser up to send a file to the server.  Apparently xhr2 and FormData let you set this up too, and FileReader lets you read local files, but all that stuff needs IE10 or a reasonable recent alternative.  Nor familiar with flash.  Anyway good luck.

Comment: @Paul you have beeen a help.  Im sure something will turn up.  Maybe an alternative would be to create a worker thread on the server that accepts the JS object, and creates the file on the server and pushes it to where it needs to go.