# Submitting basic form data with AJAX to PHP web service

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to submit some form data using jQuery / Ajax to a PHP web service (php file) and simply echo the results, for now.

Here is my index.html file

```
<html>
<head>
<title>PHP web service &amp; AJAX</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Hello! Is it me you're looking for?</h1>

    <form id="submit">
        <label>Name</label>
        <input id="name" type="text" name="name" />
        <label>Email</label>
        <input id="email" type="email" name="email" />
        <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit details" />
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".submit").click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                // BUILD DATA STRING
                var name = $("#name").val();
                var email = $("#email").val();
                var dataString = "subName=" + name + "&subEmail=" + email;

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'results.php',
                    data: dataString,
                    success: function() {
                        window.location.href = "results.php";
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

And the PHP (results.php) file

```
<?php
    echo $_POST['subName'] . "<br />" . $_POST['subEmail'];
?>
```

Having no luck so far, can anyone help me out? I've tried [this tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16616250/form-submit-with-ajax-passing-form-data-to-php-without-page-refresh) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19736272/passing-form-data-and-file-to-php-using-ajax) as well but they haven't helped.

Comment: Remove `window.location.href = "results.php";`, it is not required when using AJAX. It'll redirect the page after successful completion of AJAX giving impression that AJAX is not working and the form is submitted and redirected

Comment: @Tushar Can I leave the success function blank and the script will be fine?

Comment: Yes, use `success: function(response) { console.log(response); },`

Comment: I will also recommend to use `data: $('form').serialize(),`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the success handler you want to catch the `data` returned by the ajax call, then output it on the page using `$('#results').html(data)`. Additionally, if desired, you want to hide the form using `$('#submit').hide()`. Your code should then look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#submit").on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'results.php',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                $('#results').html(data);
                //$('#submit').hide();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Then you should add the following `div` to your page:

```
<div id="results">Results will go here</div>
```

Comment: I've got it. Logic has just clicked. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

With your code, you aren't actually looking out for the output of `results.php` and, even if you were, you're just redirecting the user to the page (which won't also `POST` any data).

What you want to do is this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'results.php',
    data: dataString,
    success: function(data) { //where "data" is the output of results.php
        alert(data); //will bring up an alert box with subName and subEmail
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

check out this awesome video where , Mr.Adam explains all the basics in  a very simple and clear way. You do not even have to make use of third party JS libraries to do the job.

This code accepts value from a form , processes it ,and returns back to client 's HTML through Javascript

Link:-
[Return data from PHP with AJAX](https://youtu.be/PbOB6dJ_f4Q)

source code :
[Source code of video](https://www.developphp.com/video/JavaScript/Ajax-Post-to-PHP-File-XMLHttpRequest-Object-Return-Data-Tutorial)

index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function ajax_post(){
                // Create our XMLHttpRequest object
                var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                // Create some variables we need to send to our PHP file
                var url = "my_parse_file.php";
                var fn = document.getElementById("first_name").value;
                var ln = document.getElementById("last_name").value;
                var vars = "firstname="+fn+"&lastname="+ln;
                hr.open("POST", url, true);
                // Set content type header information for sending url encoded variables in the request
                hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                // Access the onreadystatechange event for the XMLHttpRequest object
                hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
                        var return_data = hr.responseText;
                        document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = return_data;
                    }
                }
                // Send the data to PHP now... and wait for response to update the status div
                hr.send(vars); // Actually execute the request
                document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "processing...";
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Ajax Post to PHP and Get Return Data</h2>
        First Name: <input id="first_name" name="first_name" type="text">  <br><br>
        Last Name: <input id="last_name" name="last_name" type="text"> <br><br>
        <input name="myBtn" type="submit" value="Submit Data" onclick="ajax_post();"> <br><br>
        <div id="status"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

my_parse_file.php

```
<?php 
echo 'Thank you '. $_POST['firstname'] . ' ' . $_POST['lastname'] . ', says the PHP file';
?>
```