# Send File to PHP via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

**This is the main part of the JavaScript file.**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('form').submit(function(event)
    {
        var formData = {
            'name'          : $('input[name=name]').val(),
            'position'      : $('input[name=position]').val(),
            'resume'        : $('input[name=resume]').val(),
            'comment'       : $('#commentBox').val()
        };

        $.ajax({
            type        : 'POST',
            url         : 'process.php',
            data        : formData,
            dataType    : 'json',
            encode      : true
        })
```

It gets HTML form fields and posts them to the PHP file.

I then access all the fields via $_POST['..']

Problem is the 'resume' field only passes on a String like : "C:/fakepath/file.doc" but I need to pass on the actual object/file so I could access it with $_FILES['resume']['name'] in the PHP file.

I'm sure there is something simple I'm missing but I've stared at it far too long and Googled examples without much success.

Appreciate any assistance, criticism :)

Comment: ajax can't send files mate

Comment: You can use plugins though ex:https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/

Comment: Sending file using AJAX is possible but need some tuning: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9622901/how-to-upload-a-file-using-jquery-ajax-and-formdata

Comment: Just a follow up on this, I realized it was totally irrelevant as I was using the PHPMailer class, which provides you with a very easy method to add attachments to the emails like so: `$mail->addAttachment($fileName,$target_path);    // Optional name`

Answer (score 0):

Try this as a form data object instead - you cannot send files - but can pass its data as a file.

```
var resume = $('#resume');   
var form_data = new FormData();                  
form_data.append('file', resume);
```

...etc