# How to add files to an input file tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cropper

I wanted to add files to `<input type="file" multiple>` using js/jQuery.

Here is where am having trouble, I am using cropperjs, so I want the cropped image to be appended to data of a form and sent on submit.

Comment: If you mean that you want to automatically select a file in a file input, then I'm afraid that's not possible. Files can only be selected manually by the user for security reasons.

Comment: Given the extra detail in your edit, can the CropperJS library give you the binary data of the image output? If so you can append it to a FormData object and upload it to the server via an AJAX request instead.

Comment: Then you can dynamically create a form with input field having file type, then submit that form using javascript

Comment: @RAUSHANKUMAR no you can't, because as I mentioned in my first comment you cannot programmatically set the file/data in a `file` input.

Comment: cropperjs returns a canvas and using `toDataURL()` i convert it to binary data, but then from there how do i proceed using ajax

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i mean i guess i will have to get the form data as well so how do i put them together then before sending them

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998908/convert-data-uri-to-file-then-append-to-formdata/5100158#5100158) for how to create the FormData, and [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9622901/how-to-upload-a-file-using-jquery-ajax-and-formdata) for how to upload that FormData though AJAX.

Comment: thanks @RoryMcCrossan that really helped