# Upload a file with Ajax, jQuery and Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I am trying to upload a form with jQuery and Ajax using Laravel as server side code, my form is:

HTML:

```
  <form action="" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
       <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Comprobante</label>
       <input type="file" name="file" class="form-control" id="file" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
    </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Nombre</label>
       <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter name">
    </div>
 </form>
```

jQuery, Ajax:

```
     $( 'body' ).on( "submit", 'form', function() {
        event.preventDefault();

        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("file", $('#file')[0].files[0]);
        formData.append("name", $('#name').val());

        var formData = $(this).serialize();

        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:"{{ url('/accountability/store') }}",
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            },
            data: formData,
            success:function(html)
            {
                alert('stored!');
            }
        });
    });
```

Laravel:

```
  $extension = $request->file('file')->getClientOriginalExtension();

  $filename = $request->rut.'_rendicion_'. date('d_m_Y_h_i_s') .'.'.$extension;

  Storage::disk('dropbox')->putFileAs(
        '/intranet_jisparking_archivos_web/', 
        $request->file('file'),
        $filename
    );
```

The problem is that it says that

> Call to a member function getClientOriginalExtension() on null

But I do not understand why? because I am uploading the file with this `$('#file')[0].files[0]` in the jQuery. It looks like `$request->file('file')` is empty, how can I fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: You're setting `var formData = new FormData()` and adding the `append('file', ...)`, then promptly overriding it to `var formData = $(this).serialize();`. Could that be the issue?

Comment: [How to upload a file using jQuery.ajax and FormData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9622901/how-to-upload-a-file-using-jquery-ajax-and-formdata)

Comment: Dont use `var formData = $(this).serialize();`

Comment: Try order of execution of statement as below

var formData = $(this).serialize();
formData.append("file", $('#file')[0].files[0]);
formData.append("name", $('#name').val());

Comment: @Ruchi They don't need `serialize()` at all. The answer below demonstrates the correct logic; `new FormData()`, append then send.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var formData = new FormData();
var file = $('#file').prop('files')[0];

formData.append('file', file);
formData.append('other_variable', $('#other_variable').val());
// Don't use serialize here, as it is used when we want to send the data of entire form in a query string way and that will not work for file upload

$.ajax({
    url: '{{ url("your_url") }}',
    method: 'post',
    data: formData,
    contentType : false,
    processData : false,
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    },
    success: function(response){
        // Do what ever you want to do on sucsess
    }
});
```

In controller method, you will get the file like:

```
$file = Input::file('file');
```